# GridView representing file Manager in the same Activity

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a gridView in an Activity which shows some remote data of a Server. In particular it shows some pictures and some directories. What I want to do is when I click on a folder to show the pictures and directories inside this directory (Which will be fetched through the Internet, and a new thread will update the new View), just like a File Manager does. Is there is a way have all these gridViews a simple Activity and switch logically  between those? Furthermore, can I retrieve the data from the previous directory without re-fetching them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As I understand your question all you need is press on directory and load all data with current url, if directory is pressed, new deeper directory url appears. And you can change view by that url

Comment: Correct, how do I update the view but also save the previous state of the View? Using multidiamension ArrayList?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your comment, to save previous state of view with arraylist you can use like this:
if first view is position 1, second is position 2 and etc

```
onClickNewDirectory() {
  position = position + 1
  Object object = new Object(position, directory, ...);
  arraylist.add(object)
}

onbackToPreviousDirectory() {
  //delete last element of position
  arraylist.remove(arraylist.size() - 1);
  position = position - 1
}
```